# CSS/HTML - Hide images on mobile phone and use an alternate text

Tags: html, css, image, mobile

I currently have a page that generates a table from an SQL database using PHP, including one column that contains images. Due to us now having to work on a mobile platform, I'm looking for a way to hide the images. I'm currently using `display: none` on an `antiscreen.css` file, but as the images are links, it doesn't show the links

For clarity, when the image is on a PC browser it appears like this:

```
<td>
  <a href="link to image source:>
    <img  height=80 alt='Text I want to display' src="link to image source" />
  </a>
</td>
```

And when on a mobile the image, link and text are hidden using the `display:none` method.

So how would you recommend I work this out?

Comment: How are you determining that a device is mobile? User agent sniffing? Media Queries? Do you have any control over the output of the html?

Comment: I am using media queries using the `max-width` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do this:

```
<td>
  <a href="link to image source:>
    <img  height=80 alt='Text I want to display' src="link to image source" />
    <span class="mobileonly" src="link to image source">Text I want to display</span>
  </a>
</td>
```

Then I would set `span.mobileonly { display: none; }` on the main stylesheet and `span.mobileonly { display: inline; }` in `antiscreen.css`. The advantage is that the mobile link will also be easy to style.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, which works for all screen sizes under a certain nr. of pixels is to use a media query, basically similar to the above one but with the advantage that it works on any screen size smaller than the defined number of pixels.

```
    /* Media Query for mobile */

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {  

    /* This resizes tables and images to be 100% wide with a proportionate width */

    /* Hide stuff on mobiles */
    table[class=emailnomob],td[class=emailnomob],img[class=emailnomob],span[class=emailnomob]{display:none !important;}

    /* Additional Media Query for tablets */

    @media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

    /* Hide stuff on tablets */
    table[class=emailnomob],td[class=emailnomob],img[class=emailnomob],span[class=emailnomob]{display:none !important;}
```

This should covers both mobile and tablet devices.

Code courtesy of .net email tutorial. I only stripped the parts you don't need.

**Usage:**

```
<img class="emailnomob" height=80 alt="Text I want to display" src="link to image source" />
```